# Querying Stackoverflow public dataset on BigQuery - SQL multiple join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on Stackoverflow posts & comments extraction. There are three tables: questions, answers, and comments. The schemas for them are shown below, and you can also look at them in [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/public-datasets/google-bigquery-public-datasets-now-include-stack-overflow-q-a).

Basically, I intend to retrieve all the comments, questions, and answers that share the same tags.

The questions schema:

[image]

`tags` is the question tag collections looking like `javascript|node.js|stream|buffer` in content.

The answers schema:

[image]

`parent_id` is the corresponding question id for the answer.

The comment schema:

[image]

`post_id` is its attached post id, regardless the post is a question or answer.

For instance, how to extract all the questions, answers, and comments that share `tensorflow` tag? I appreciate your help!

The expected extracted tables look like this:

```
question.id|question.title|question.body|answer.id|answer.title|answer.body
```

and

```
question.id|question.title|question.body|comment.id|comment.text
```

and

```
answer.id|answer.title|answer.body|comment.id|comment.text
```

The fields are too many for all, so I just name a few to make things clear. For the first table, I already have it by SQL enquiry:

```
select * 
from question
left outer join answer
on answer.parent_id = question.id
where question.tags like "%tensorflow%"
```

Comment: Take a SQL 101 class

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact, I haven't touched SQL for years. I would consider retaking it later on. But can you give me a concrete solution now? I appreciate it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Just all lines for each table that contains a tag ? from same question ? Could you please edit the question and add an output table of what you want ?

Comment: @ewertonvsilva I edited it a bit, what is your confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some ways to do so. The is is that a question may have multiple answers, so you can return the question repeated  with all its answers, or you can use arrays and structs to return each question once, with all its multiple answers.

---

- Easy way, same question multiple times (use `left join` because you can't have an answer without a question):

```sql
select q.tags question_tag, q.id question_id, q.title question_title, q.body question_body, a.id answer_id, a.body from `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` as q
left join
`bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` as a
on a.parent_id = q.id
where regexp_contains(q.tags, 'java');
```

- Using arrays and structs to return the question each time with all its answers:

```sql
with agg_answer as (
select parent_id, ARRAY_AGG(struct(id,body)) from `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` group by parent_id
)
select q.tags question_tag, q.id question_id, q.title question_title, q.body question_body, a.*
from 
`bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` as q
left join 
agg_answer as a
on q.id = a.parent_id
where regexp_contains(q.tags,'tensorflow');
```

---

- same for `question` **x** `comments`:

---

```sql
with agg_comments as (
select post_id, ARRAY_AGG(struct(id,text)) from `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.comments` group by post_id
)
select q.tags question_tag, q.id question_id, q.title question_title, q.body question_body, c.*
from 
`bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` as q
left join 
agg_comments as c
on q.id = c.post_id
where regexp_contains(q.tags,'java' )
-- questions with or without comments ( remove follow line for all questions)
and c.post_id is not null;
```

```sql
select q.tags, q.id question_id, q.title question_title, q.body question_body, a.id answer_id, a.text comment_text from `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` as q
left join
`bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.comments` as a
on a.post_id = q.id
where regexp_contains(q.tags, 'java')
-- questions with or without comments ( remove follow line for all questions)
and a.post_id is not null;
```

---

repeat for other tables you want.